# Creating change function with jQuery iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, foreach

My goal here is to be able to add preferences to a form I've made... I've created an array of objects containing the following fields like so...

```js
var preferences =[{
  base_field:"field1",
  base_value:"1",
  preference_type:"change",
  target_field:"field2_div legend",
  target_value:"New Field 2 Legend"
},
{
  base_field:"field1",
  base_value:"2",
  preference_type:"change",
  target_field:"field2_div legend",
  target_value:"New Field 2 Legend"
}];

$.each(preferences, function(key, preference){
  var baseField = $("#" + preference.base_field);
  var baseValue = preference.base_value;
  var targetField = $("#" + preference.target_field);
  var targetValue = preference.target_value;
  
  if (preference.preference_type == 'change') {
    var originalValue = targetField.text();
    baseField.change(function(){
      if(baseField.val() === baseValue){
        targetField.text(targetValue);
      }
      if(baseField.val() !== baseValue){
        targetField.text(originalValue);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="field1_div">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Field 1 Legend</legend>
    <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
    <select id="field1" name="field1">
      <option value="" selected>Field 1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="field2_div">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Default Field 2 Legend</legend>
    <input id="field2" type="text" name="field2">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I want the text of '#field2_div legend' to change when the value of #field1 changes to '1' or '2' from 'Default Field 2 Legend' to 'New Field 2 Legend', and then if field1 changes to a value that is not '1' or '2', the text of '#field2_div legend' is restored to 'Default Field 2 Legend'

My problem is only the last change function sticks for when field1 = "2"... I think this is because the change function is getting overwritten. Any ideas on how to rewrite this for a more scalable approach?

Comment: You're creating two change event handlers, one for each rule.  It's not being overwritten.  Why do you have two base value preference rules for the same element?

Comment: @Taplar I need to be able to set the text of '#field2_div legend' to 'New Field 2 Legend' whenever 1 or 2 is the value of '#field1' - so the base value would be either 1 or 2, hence the 2 rules.

Comment: You're binding two change events to the same `select`, they'll be executed one by one, so you'll only see the change of the last event you bind.

Comment: @SamCraven surely for that you just need one rule containing two fields, one for each base value it can switch from? Or maybe an array of base values, for added flexibility? Because apart from that, your rules are identical and it seems just like redundant duplication.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory any ideas on how I could rewrite this into a single change function that checks for all of the preference-defined base values and updates the target field accordingly?

Comment: @ADyson That makes sense... So I guess I could replace the key of base_value to an array ["1","2"] and then check if baseValue.val() is in that array.

Comment: @SamCraven yes, I think that would be easier and it would remove the possibility of creating the event twice, because there's only one actual rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like this... Thanks @ADyson !

```js
var preferences =[{
  base_field:"field1",
  base_value:["1","2"],
  preference_type:"change",
  target_field:"field2_div legend",
  target_value:"New Field 2 Legend"
}];

$.each(preferences, function(key, preference){
  var baseField = $("#" + preference.base_field);
  var baseValue = preference.base_value;
  var targetField = $("#" + preference.target_field);
  var targetValue = preference.target_value;
  
  if (preference.preference_type == 'change') {
    var originalValue = targetField.text();
    baseField.change(function(){
      if($.inArray(baseField.val(), baseValue) > -1){
        targetField.text(targetValue);
      } else{
        targetField.text(originalValue);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="field1_div">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Field 1 Legend</legend>
    <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
    <select id="field1" name="field1">
      <option value="" selected>Field 1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="field2_div">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Default Field 2 Legend</legend>
    <input id="field2" type="text" name="field2">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach when changing values on the fly in a form.
I left you some work to customize it to your liking.

```
<div id="field1_div">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Field 1 Legend</legend>
        <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
        <select id="field1" name="field1">
            <option value="" selected>Field 1</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="field2_div">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Default Field 2 Legend</legend>
        <input id="field2" type="text" name="field2">
    </fieldset>
</div>

<script>
    function formChanger(inputValue) {
        switch (inputValue) {
            case '1':
                // do something for selection 1
                console.log('selected 1');
                break;
            case '2':
                // do something for selection 2
                console.log('selected 2');
                break;
            case '3':
                // do something for selection 2
                console.log('selected 3');
                break;
            case '4':
                // do something for selection 2
                console.log('selected 4');
                break;
            default :
                // Probably want to remove any of the first 4 options that may have been implemented already.
                return null;
        }
    }
    $('#field1').change(function(){
        formChanger($(this).val());

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think the switch wouldn't work since the `inputValue` is a string `"1" != 1` in switch case condition.

Answer (score 0):

add your code like following

```js
$(function(){ 
 
 $('#field1').change(function(){
  if($.inArray($(this).val(), ['1','2']) >= 0){   
   $('#field2_div').children().find('legend').text('New Field 2 Legend');
  }else{
   $('#field2_div').children().find('legend').text('Default Field 2 Legend');
  }
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="field1_div">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Field 1 Legend</legend>
  <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
  <select id="field1" name="field1">
   <option value="" selected>Field 1</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="field2_div">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Default Field 2 Legend</legend>
  <input id="field2" type="text" name="field2">
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer works but it is not dynamic to the array of preferences... Not sure why you are using find() after children()... seems redundant.

Comment: you can create an array and assign the values to the array. you already decide the values right, 1 and 2.. you can assign.